# Find the number of times a name occurs in each 'month year' using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like

```
 x        d   y

bbc  Sep 2020  123
rsb  Sep 2020  234
atc  Sep 2020  345
svc  Sep 2020  543
mwe  Sep 2020  567
bpa  Oct 2020  322
mwe  Oct 2020  456
uhs  Oct 2020  786
se   Oct 2020  543
db   Oct 2020  778
rsb  Nov 2020  358
svc  Nov 2020  678
db   Nov 2020  321
rb   Nov 2020  689
bpa  Nov 2020  765
```

The column `'d'` is in `as.yearmon` format

I wanna find out the values in `x` column that are repeated for each `month year` column `d`.

In this dataframe `bpa` and `db` are present in `Nov 2020` and `Oct 2020`. So the output needs to be like

```
 names_present present_for
    bpa            2
    db             2
```

The values of `x` present in each `month year` data should be given as output only if they are present continuosly. Here `svc` is present in `Nov 2020` and  `Sep 2020` but it cannot be considered as a part of the output since it is absent in `Oct 2020`.

I tried splitting the dataframe based on the `df$d` column but I couldn't loop through the split dataframes and get the output required. the split dataframe looks like

```
$`Nov 2020`
     x        d   y
11 rsb Nov 2020 358
12 svc Nov 2020 678
13  db Nov 2020 321
14  rb Nov 2020 689
15 bpa Nov 2020 765

$`Oct 2020`
     x        d   y
6  bpa Oct 2020 322
7  mwe Oct 2020 456
8  uhs Oct 2020 786
9   se Oct 2020 543
10  db Oct 2020 778

$`Sep 2020`
    x        d   y
1 bbc Sep 2020 123
2 rsb Sep 2020 234
3 atc Sep 2020 345
4 svc Sep 2020 543
5 mwe Sep 2020 567
```

The code needs to first check in the most recent `month year` followed by the previous `month year` and so on. Check if any of the `x` names are present in `Nov 2020` first and then followed by `Oct 2020` and then `Sep 2020` and count their occurrences. if the names are present in `Nov 2020` and `Sep 2020` but not in `Oct 2020`, then it cannot be considered as a part of the output dataframe. There can be any number of `month year` values. The dataframe given here is just a small sample. I wanna dynamically find out this information.

I've been struggling with this for a long time. Would be great if anyone could help me solve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If bpa and db are **also** present in Sep 2020, would your output be bpa (3), db(3), mwe(2) ? (because db and bpa would be co-present in three consecutive months, and mwe would be co-present with bpa and db in 2 months?).. Basically, I'm asking if you can make your example a bit more complicated/nuanced - as it is currently shown, I can extract that result easily, but I'm unsure about the nuance of more complicated situations

Comment: @langtang Yes, if bpa and db are also present in Sep 2020, output would be bpa (3) and db (3) but mwe(2) would not be there because its not present in the most recent month year (ie) Nov 2020. The most recent month's data has to be checked first, followed by the previous and so on. This is the problem I'm facing.